# Strange behaviour - body width change, div becomes opaque

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a very strange problem with my responsive css. The body is 90% wide.

If the horizontal resolution goes below 1200px, I change it to 100% (with media queries), but in resolution below 1000px it should be 100% again.

My page has two centered containers, the other on the left side is below (behind with z-index) the right one and it has a background image. Both containers have fluid width.

So basically when the screen width goes below a certain point, the left container with the image goes little be under the right one. The right container has a margin from 20px to leave some space. This 20px margin should be transparent.

This is working fine, but if I scale the browser between 1000px and 1200px, the margin from the right content container becomes opaque, but it should not. It should be transparent, as it is in wider width.

I do not know where this behaviour comes from, since I do not change anything at the margins.

Just scale your browser to a width between 1000px and 1200px then you see the green gap between the image and content. (and if you scale litte more tahn 1200px, you see that the margin is transparent again)

Sorry bit difficult to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't become opaque.

The problem is not with the right div overlapping the left. The problem is with the left div width.

It is 40% and that starts to become less than the image once your browser becomes too narrow.

If you add a `min-width:780px` to the left div it will work. and since it is fixed and with a lower z-index you do not need to worry about its size..

Comment: OMG how embarrassing you are so right *facepalm* I guess this is a perfect example of not to see the wood for the trees. Time for lunch...

Comment: Basically, the background image is being clipped as the container shrinks in width.  An alternative solution would be to scale the background to fit the container width.